# Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3 crashes

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-4.0

Starting today my Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3 crashes ones it sees code in the text editor. I can open a solution without opening the files just fine, but I get the error below if the text editor is open with code. To be more exact I can even open default.aspx files, but it crashes on my default.aspx.vb file!

I already tried to repair Visual Studio. This didn't work. I tried reinstall Visual Studio, this didn't work either. 
I found some corrupt files on my Windows 8.1 related to .NET Framework, but after repairing I still get the error.

UPDATE: It is probably an extension problem. Uninstalling [AJAX Control Toolkit](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/AJAX-Control-Toolkit) didn't resolve the problem though. Also uninstall of Visual Studio and cleaning up the install directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions) and then reinstall didn't work. 
In the end I reinstalled Windows and installed Update 3, this worked.

This is the error in the Event Viewer:

> Application: devenv.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task) at Microsoft.Alm.Remoting.AsyncRemotingServices+d__1`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task) at Microsoft.Alm.Remoting.RemoteServiceProvider+<GetServiceAsync>d__12.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task) at Microsoft.Alm.Remoting.RemoteServiceProviderExtensions+<GetServiceAsync>d__0`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Alm.Roslyn.Client.VisualStudioWorkspaceHost+d__37.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__6_0(System.Object) at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate) at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl() at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue() at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object) at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate) at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)

Comment: I've the same problem too. reinstalled Windows? this is a last option for me.

Comment: hope you found an other solution, I tried everything before the reinstall..